# Api return null while fetch data from MySQL in Retrofit Android

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to fetch data from MySql database. Api return null for particular id while return perfectly for other conditions. I'm new in php therefore didn't get where the actual error is.

Function:

```php
public function getAllQuestion($topic_id){

    $output = $this->con->prepare("select quiz_id,topic_id,question,possible_answer,
    correct_answer from quiz where topic_id = ?;");

    $output->bind_param("i",$topic_id);
    $output->execute();
    $output->bind_result($quiz_id,$topic_id,$question,$possible_answer,$correct_answer);

    $questions = array();

    while($output->fetch()){
    $q = array();
    $q['quiz_id'] = $quiz_id;
    $q['topic_id'] = $topic_id;
    $q['question'] = $question;
    $q['possible_answer'] = $possible_answer;
    $q['correct_answer'] = $correct_answer;

    array_push($questions,$q);
    }
    return $questions;
}
```

When i pass topic_id 1 or 2, postman show data:
[image]

But when i pass topic_id = 11, it return nothing:
[image]

However for topic_id 11, query run perfectly on MySql:
[image]

Comment: @NJInamdar - What code snippets have the OP posted as images? As far as I can see, the code is in text. It's just the expected result that is an image (which, imho, is fair in this case)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is in Binds variables to a prepared statement. Fixed with:

> https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php

Answer (score -1):

In your bindparam line, try replacing 'i' with just 1 (no quotes)

Comment: Like that `$output->bind_param(1,$topic_id);` @ShaneWeeks

Comment: mysqli_stmt::bind_param(): Undefined fieldtype 1 (parameter 2)

Comment: I was thinking that bind Param was looking for a literal 'i' to replace instead of replacing at first occurrence of '?'. I'm confusing myself with PDO, sorry!

Comment: The first argument to `bind_param()` is the types. `i` = integer, `s` = string, `d` = double and ``b` = blob. Here's [the manual](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php).

Comment: So @MagnusEriksson Did you tell me where the actual error is !

Comment: @AWAISCHAUDARY - I don't know what the issue is, but this answer is not it.